# Scala: how to specify varargs as type?

Tags: scala, types

Instead of

```
def foo(configuration: (String, String)*)
```

I'd like to be able to write:

```
type Configuration =  (String, String)*
def foo(configuration: Configuration)
```

The main use case is to provide an easy method signature when overriding in subclasses

UPDATE:
I can come close by

```
type Param = (String, String)
def foo(configuration: Param*)
```

But is there a way of doing it better?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the `*` is only allowed on a ParamType, that is the type of a parameter to a anonymous function or a method.

> 4.6.2 Repeated Parameters Syntax: ParamType ::= Type ‘*’ The last value
>   parameter of a parameter section may
>   be suffixed by “*”, e.g. (..., x:T *).
>   The type of such a repeated parameter
>   inside the method is then the sequence
>   type scala.Seq[T ]. Methods with
>   repeated parameters T * take a
>   variable number of arguments of type T.

The compiler bug @Eastsun's example is in the first line, not the second. This should not be allowed:

```
scala> type VarArgs =  (Any*)
defined type alias VarArgs
```

I've raised a [bug](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3180).

This is similar restriction to By-Name Parameters. In this case, the compiler prevents the creation of the type alias:

```
scala> type LazyString = (=> String) <console>:1: error: no by-name parameter type allowed here
       type LazyString = (=> String)
```

Your final attempt is the standard way to express this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use

```
type Configuration =  ((String, String)*)
def foo(configuration: Configuration)
```

But it makes the compiler crash(2.8.0.r21161-b20100314020123). It seems a bug of the scala compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You could define it as

```
type Param = (String, String)
type Configuration = Seq[Param]

def foo(configuration : Configuration)
```

the user has to construct a Seq instance

```
foo(List("1"->"2"))
```

which is not optimal.